# Programatically capture styles in HTML files and convert to Word document with PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, ms-word

I'm working on a script that will scrape the HTML files of 30+ talks given at a bi-annual conference for printing. Word has been chosen as the tool to print from. The talks have bold, italics, outlines, headers and other style-related elements. I need to capture all of these styles into the word document without manual intervention. I've tried two approaches to this problem.

1. Target each talk and cherry-pick the elements that contain the relevant information (title, speaker, paragraphs, etc). This works beautifully, but the style is missing. Is there a way to retain the style information with this method?

   Full code example below to show everything working together:

   ```
   $primaryURL = "https://www.domain.tld/folder?lang=eng"
   $baseURL = $primaryURL.Split("`?")[0]
   $talkArray = @()
   $content = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $primaryURL).Content
   $links = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $primaryURL).Links
   $talkLinks = $links | Where {$_.outerHTML -like "*/folder/$year/$month*"} | Select -expand href
   $talkInfo = $links | Where {$_.outerHTML -like "*/folder/$year/$month*"} | Select -expand outerText
   $domainName = $baseUrl.Split("/")[2]
   Foreach ($talk in $talkInfo)
   {
       $title = ($talk.Split("`n`r") -replace "`#.*", "$([char]0)" -replace "#.*" -replace "$([char]"0", "#" -replace "^\s*" -replace "\s*$")" | ? { $_; })[1]
       $speaker = ($talk.Split("`n`r") -replace "`#.*", "$([char]0)" -replace "#.*" -replace "$([char]"0", "#" -replace "^\s*" -replace "\s*$")" | ? { $_; })[2]
       $link = "https://" + $domainName + $talkLinks[$count]

       $obj = New-Object PSObject
       $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Title" -Value $title
       $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Speaker" -Value $speaker
       $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "url" -Value $link
       $talkArray += $obj
       $count++
   }
   $wordDocPath = "U:\" + $month + " " + $year + " Conference.docx"
   $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
   $word.Visible = $false
   $doc = $word.documents.add()
   $doc.Styles["No Spacing"].ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
   $doc.Styles["No Spacing"].ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
   $margin = 36 # 0.5 inches
   $doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = $margin
   $doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = $margin
   $doc.PageSetup.TopMargin = $margin
   $doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = $margin
   $selection = $word.Selection

   $outputPath = $wordDocPath
   $doc.SaveAs($outputPath)
   $doc.Close()
   $word.Quit()
   $word = $null

   $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
   $objWord.Visible = $false 
   $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($wordDocPath)
   $objSelection = $objWord.Selection
   $trash = $objSelection.EndKey(6, 0)
   $objSelection.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2)

   ForEach ($talk in $talkArray)
   {
       $talkTitle = $talk.Title
       $a, $p, $results, $wrap, $n = $null
       $talkContent = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $talk.url
       $speakerPic = "https:" + ($talkContent.images | Where {$_.alt -like "$talkTitle"}).src
       $picName = (($talkContent.images | Where {$_.alt -like "$talkTitle"}).src).Split("/")[-1]
       $kicker = ($talkContent.ParsedHTML.GetElementByID('kicker1')).innerHTML
       $count = 3
       $line = 1

       # - Download the picture
       $picPath = $tempDir + "\" + $picName
       Download-File -url $speakerPic -file $picPath

       # - Write the header information
       $text = $talkTitle
       $objSelection.Style="Heading 1"
       $objSelection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
       $objSelection.TypeText($text)
       $objSelection.TypeParagraph()
       $text = $talk.Speaker + "`r`n"
       $objSelection.Font.Bold = 1
       $objSelection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
       $objSelection.TypeText("by $text")
       $objSelection.Font.Bold = 0
       $objSelection.TypeParagraph()
       $objShape = $objDoc.Shapes
       $wrap = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType]::wdWrapSquare # WdWrapTopBottom
       $objShape.AddPicture($picPath) | Out-Null
       $objShape.Range(1).WrapFormat.Type = $wrap
       $objSelection.Endkey()
       $objSelection.Font.Bold = 1
       $objSelection.Font.Italic = 1
       $objSelection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
       $objSelection.TypeText($kicker)
       $objSelection.TypeParagraph()
       $objSelection.Font.Bold = 0
       $objSelection.Font.Italic = 0

       # - Collect the paragraphs
       $paragraphs = @()
       do
       {
           [string]$p = ($talkContent.ParsedHTML.getElementById("p$count")).InnerText
           if ($p) {
               $obj = New-Object PSObject
               $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "p" -Value $p
               $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "line" -Value $line
               $paragraphs += $obj
               $line = $line + 1
           }
           Else {
           }
           $count = $count + 1
       } while ($p)

       # - Write the paragraphs
       $paragraphs | % {
           $results = [regex]::Split($_.p,'(?<![\d\s])(?<![\(\s])(?<![\:\s])(?<![\-\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)')
           $line = $_.line

           $objSelection.Style="Normal"
           $objSelection.Font.SuperScript = 0
           $objSelection.Font.Size = 9
           $objSelection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
           $objSelection.TypeText("$line. ")
           foreach ($item in $results)
           {
               $text = $item
               if ($text -match '(?<![\d\s])(?<![\(\s])(?<![\:\s])(?<![\-\s])(\d{1,2})(?!\d)')
               {
                   $objSelection.Font.SuperScript = 1
                   $objSelection.TypeText("$text")
                   $objSelection.Font.SuperScript = 0
               }
               Else
               {
                   if ($text -ne " ")
                   {
                       #$objSelection.Style="Normal"
                       $objSelection.Font.SuperScript = 0
                       $objSelection.Font.Size = 9
                       $objSelection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                       $objSelection.TypeText("$text")
                   }
               }

           }
           $objSelection.TypeParagraph()
       }

       $count = 1
       # - Work on the notes
       $notes = @()
       $line = 1
       do
       {
           [string]$n = ($talkContent.ParsedHTML.getElementById("note$count")).InnerText
           if ($n) 
           {
               $obj = New-Object PSObject
               $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "n" -Value $n -Force
               $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "line" -Value $line -Force
               $notes += $obj
               $line = $line + 1
           }
           Else {
           }
           $count = $count + 1
       } while ($n)
       $text = "`vNOTES:"
       $objSelection.TypeText("$text")
       $objSelection.TypeParagraph()

       $notes | % {
           $note = $_.n
           $line = $_.line
           $text = $note
           $objSelection.Font.Size = 9
           $objSelection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
           $objSelection.TypeText("$line. $text")
           $objSelection.TypeText("`r`n")
       }
       $objSelection.InsertNewPage()
   }

   $objDoc.saveas($wordDocPath)
   $objDoc.close()
   $objWord.quit()
   $objWord = $null
   ```

An example paragraph from the html (with style elements):

```
    <p id="p1">This is an example with <em>italic</em> text and <strong>bold</strong> text.</p>
```

2. Dump each HTML file, clean it up, then convert to Word. This preserves the style, but it's become very cumbersome to strip out all the junk (web headers, links and menus at the top, footers, links and navigation buttons at the bottom) that I've almost given up. Perhaps there is a simpler way? Code example below:

   ```
   # Code snipped. This version performs similar functions to collect information on each talk, creates the temp folder and the word doc. Then:

   [ref]$SaveFormat = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type]
   $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
   $word.visible = $false
   $document = $word.documents.open($htmlPath)
   $selection = $word.Selection
   $paras = $document.Paragraphs
   foreach ($para in $paras) 
   { 
       $text = $para.Range.Text
       If ($text -like "$title*")
       {
           break
       }
       Else
       {
           $para.Range.Select()
           $selection.Cut()
       }
   }
   $document.saveas([ref] $wordDocPath, [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault)
   $document.close()
   $word.Quit() 
   $word = $null
   ```

This is not the complete code to strip the offending elements, but it starts by chucking everything before the talk title element. There are additional lines after this that must be deleted, then as I mentioned, several elements after the talk's paragraphs. After this, I will need to process each paragraph in Word to match the font, size, columns, headers, etc for the final product.

Questions:

1. Which method would you pursue?
2. If method 1, how can I translate style elements from the paragraph markers to the Word Document?
3. If method 2, is there a better way to process the document so that I can zero in on the elements I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach.

1. Scrape and save the part you want as `html_file`.
2. Use `Range.Insertfile(html_file)` which will retain all the styles in `html`.